# Libgdx: How to detect touch on a separate stage actor?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create a game which is something like this:

Play area - No stage (scene2D) used.
In the play area, in render method:

```
b2dr.render(world, b2dcam.combined); // main camera
sb.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
hud.stage.draw(); // draws HUD over screen
```

I've touchDown/touchUp/touchDragged events defiend in play area and they work good. Inside HUD, I'm making use of a stage and a table to show it properly.

Now lets say I've a button in HUD on which I want to receive click events. How do I do that? I tried this inside my HUD class but no success:

```
myBtn.addListener(new InputListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                System.out.println("touchdown");
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                System.out.println("touchup");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you set inputprocessor to your stage? If not do so in create method or constructor by calling Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

Comment: Also you should calling stage.act(delta); in every iteration.